# Solr Repeaters/Slaves replicating are every commit on Master instead of Optimize

Tags: solr, lucene, solr7

I have a Master-Repeater-Slave configuration. Master/Slaves/Repeaters is setup with this replication configs `<str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>`, full config below

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
    <str name="commitReserveDuration">01:00:00</str>
    <lst name="master">
      <str name="enable">${Project.enable.master:false}</str>
      <str name="replicateAfter">${Project.master.setReplicateAfterCommit:}</str>
      <str name="replicateAfter">${Project.master.setReplicateAfterStartup:}</str>
      <str name="replicateAfter">optimize</str>
      <str name="confFiles"></str>
    </lst>
    <lst name="slave">
      <str name="enable">${Project.enable.slave:false}</str>
      <str name="masterUrl">/solr/someCoreName</str>
      <str name="pollInterval">${Newton.replication.pollInterval:00:02:00}</str>
  </requestHandler>
```

Repeaters are configured to poll every 1 sec.
N Slaves are configured to poll at different intervals so as not to overwhelm the repeater with download requests, eg: 2,4,6,8 minutes. 
Both via java startup command args.

Now, given that I issue optimize on Master index every 2 hours on master, I expect master to make a replicable version available only after optimize. But it seems that, master generation increases after every commit which happens after `X` (configurable) minutes and repeater and slaves get the unoptimized (but recent state with latest committed data).

```
<updateHandler class="solr.DirectUpdateHandler2">
    <updateLog>
      <str name="dir">some/dir</str>
    </updateLog>

    <autoCommit>
      <maxDocs>10000000</maxDocs>
      <maxTime>${Project.autoCommit.maxTime:60000}</maxTime>
      <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
    </autoCommit>
  </updateHandler>
```

Repeater/Slave logs after they see Master Generation increment

```
2019-08-31 14:48:05,544 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Master's generation: 6
2019-08-31 14:48:05,544 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Master's version: 1567288083960
2019-08-31 14:48:05,544 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Slave's generation: 5
2019-08-31 14:48:05,544 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Slave's version: 1567288023785
2019-08-31 14:48:05,544 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Starting replication process
2019-08-31 14:48:05,563 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Number of files in latest index in master: 66
2019-08-31 14:48:05,624 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState][changeWriter()] - New IndexWriter is ready to be used.
2019-08-31 14:48:05,627 [INFO ][indexFetcher-15-thread-1][solr.handler.IndexFetcher][fetchLatestIndex()] - Starting download (fullCopy=false) to MMapDirectory@/data/<path>/index.20190831144805564 lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@416c5340
```

## Question:

How do I absolutely make sure that I only allow index from Master to Repeaters/Slaves to flow through only after my issued optimize command is complete?

## Note

Once I issue optimize, optimized index with 1 segment does flow as expected to Repeaters/Slave but intermediate commits which happen on master also results in Repeaters/Slaves downloading part of the new index making their segment count > 1 and slowing search as seraching on segment size > 1 costs more than searching on segment size 1. I want new index only after periodical (programmed in code) optimize command is issued and not after every commit. I actually removed commit duration on master and then it only incremented its Generation after optimize, but if I remove commit altogether then we are risk of losing uncommitted data between 2 optimize cycles and machines happens to die in between those 2 cycles.

## Solr/luceneMatchVersion Version

7.7.1

I also tried adding in mergePolicyfactor configs but behaviour is still the same

```
<mergePolicyFactory class="org.apache.solr.index.TieredMergePolicyFactory">
      <int name="maxMergeAtOnce">32</int>
      <int name="segmentsPerTier">32</int>
    </mergePolicyFactory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `<replicateAfter>commit</replicateAfter>` to `<replicateAfter>optimize</replicateAfter>`

Also, If it does not work, try removing the polling interval configuration from the slaves.

What you are seeing is expected behaviour for solr and nothing is unusual. Try out the changes and I hope it should work fine.

Comment: actually changing to ```<replicateAfter>commit</replicateAfter>``` works, so lucene documentation to have it that way if you want Repeater -Master communication to happen only after optimize on Master works as expected. Hope this helps folks.